# Where is google chrome local storage saved?

Tags: html, local-storage

Some websites show local storage being used (in Google Chrome: `CTRL+I`, resources tab, Local Storage).

For example, StackOverflow has a "login-prefs" key with my default sign-in provider(?). So from what I can tell it is a json object.

Where on my computer would that data be stored (Ubuntu and Windows)? (or is it not stored once the browser is closed?)

Comment: An application will store data using local storage, but I want to be able to transfer that data to someone else afterwards.

Comment: It's browser specific, so whichever path is specified by any particular browser. I would assume somewhere with the cookies or at least in the program hierarchy.

Comment: In windows %LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Storage

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Local storage data is stored in your chrome profile(usually `Default`) under `Local Storage`
`%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Storage`

Answer (score 4):

There are two types of storage, key-value pairs are stored in a sqlite database and file are stored in your profile. This can change in future Chrome versions.

Answer (score 2):

Google chrome store the local storage data on the following location:

```
\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Storage\leveldb\006911.log
```

I use: windows 10
Version 62.0.3202.75 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 1):

on macOS, looks like it is in `~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Local\ Storage/leveldb`